# How to programmatically insert post excerpt block in Gutenberg block editor with content?

Tags: wordpress, post, block

I know inserting core/heading or core/paragraph with content but it was not working when inserting core/post-excerpt as -

```
let postExcerpt   = 'Excerpt content here';
let insertedBlock = wp.blocks.createBlock( 'core/post-excerpt', {               
        content: postExcerpt,               
    }); 
    
wp.data.dispatch('core/block-editor').insertBlocks( [insertedBlock ]);
// Save the post
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).savePost();
```

It is inserting new post-excerpt block but not adding any content.

I did also try 'excerpt: postExcerpt' instead of 'content: postExcerpt' but didn't work.

I am missing something I think.
Thanks in advance.